# Mapping between Wingdings/Symbol characters and their Unicode equivalents

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, ms-word

MsWord uses Wingdings and Symbol characters for bullets, by default their hex values are F0A7 and F0B7.  I want to convert the bullets to their Unicode equivalents.  Of course, it depends on the actual font used, so F0A7 Wingding would become Unicode 25AA (●).  I've found a partial mapping from [Wingdings to Unicode](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html) and from [Symbol to Unicode](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/symbol.html). Is there a general a library (preferably in Java) or database for these mappings?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; that page is the only table I've seen. If the emoji-in-Unicode proposal goes ahead, more of Wingdings might have sensible mappings, eg. 0x24 readingglasses -> U+1F453 EYEGLASSES, 0x25 bell -> U+1F514 BELL...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this question was asked, a large number of dingbat and emoji characters have been added to Unicode, some for the explicit purpose of [Wingdings/Webdings compatibility](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2011/11344-wingdings.pdf), and Unicode now has [an official list of code points](https://www.unicode.org/wg2/docs/n4384.pdf) for them.

So, here is my attempt at mapping the Wingdings and Webdings encodings to Unicode.  All of these glyphs are present in the [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/%7Eg1951d/Symbola.zip) font.  In other fonts, many of the glyphs will display as boxes or question marks.

### Wingdings

- 0x21 =  U+1F589 LOWER LEFT PENCIL
- 0x22 = ✂ U+2702 BLACK SCISSORS
- 0x23 = ✁ U+2701 UPPER BLADE SCISSORS
- 0x24 =  U+1F453 EYEGLASSES
- 0x25 =  U+1F56D RINGING BELL
- 0x26 =  U+1F56E BOOK
- 0x27 =  U+1F56F CANDLE
- 0x28 =  U+1F57F BLACK TOUCHTONE TELEPHONE
- 0x29 = ✆ U+2706 TELEPHONE LOCATION SIGN
- 0x2A =  U+1F582 BACK OF ENVELOPE
- 0x2B =  U+1F583 STAMPED ENVELOPE
- 0x2C =  U+1F4EA CLOSED MAILBOX WITH LOWERED FLAG
- 0x2D =  U+1F4EB CLOSED MAILBOX WITH RAISED FLAG
- 0x2E =  U+1F4EC OPEN MAILBOX WITH RAISED FLAG
- 0x2F =  U+1F4ED OPEN MAILBOX WITH LOWERED FLAG
- 0x30 =  U+1F5C0 FOLDER
- 0x31 =  U+1F5C1 OPEN FOLDER
- 0x32 =  U+1F5CE DOCUMENT
- 0x33 =  U+1F5CF PAGE
- 0x34 =  U+1F5D0 PAGES
- 0x35 =  U+1F5C4 FILE CABINET
- 0x36 = ⏳ U+23F3 HOURGLASS WITH FLOWING SAND
- 0x37 =  U+1F5AE WIRED KEYBOARD
- 0x38 =  U+1F5B0 TWO BUTTON MOUSE
- 0x39 =  U+1F5B2 TRACKBALL
- 0x3A =  U+1F5B3 OLD PERSONAL COMPUTER
- 0x3B =  U+1F5B4 HARD DISK
- 0x3C =  U+1F5AB WHITE HARD SHELL FLOPPY DISK
- 0x3D =  U+1F5AC SOFT SHELL FLOPPY DISK
- 0x3E = ✇ U+2707 TAPE DRIVE
- 0x3F = ✍ U+270D WRITING HAND
- 0x40 =  U+1F58E LEFT WRITING HAND
- 0x41 = ✌ U+270C VICTORY HAND
- 0x42 =  U+1F58F TURNED OK HAND SIGN
- 0x43 =  U+1F44D THUMBS UP SIGN
- 0x44 =  U+1F44E THUMBS DOWN SIGN
- 0x45 = ☜ U+261C WHITE LEFT POINTING INDEX
- 0x46 = ☞ U+261E WHITE RIGHT POINTING INDEX
- 0x47 = ☝ U+261D WHITE UP POINTING INDEX
- 0x48 =  U+1F597 WHITE DOWN POINTING LEFT HAND INDEX
- 0x49 =  U+1F590 RAISED HAND WITH FINGERS SPLAYED
- 0x4A = ☺ U+263A WHITE SMILING FACE
- 0x4B =  U+1F610 NEUTRAL FACE
- 0x4C = ☹ U+2639 WHITE FROWNING FACE
- 0x4D =  U+1F4A3 BOMB
- 0x4E =  U+1F571 BLACK SKULL AND CROSSBONES
- 0x4F =  U+1F3F3 WAVING WHITE FLAG
- 0x50 =  U+1F3F1 WHITE PENNANT
- 0x51 = ✈ U+2708 AIRPLANE
- 0x52 = ☼ U+263C WHITE SUN WITH RAYS
- 0x53 =  U+1F322 BLACK DROPLET
- 0x54 = ❄ U+2744 SNOWFLAKE
- 0x55 =  U+1F546 WHITE LATIN CROSS
- 0x56 = ✞ U+271E SHADOWED WHITE LATIN CROSS
- 0x57 =  U+1F548 CELTIC CROSS
- 0x58 = ✠ U+2720 MALTESE CROSS
- 0x59 = ✡ U+2721 STAR OF DAVID
- 0x5A = ☪ U+262A STAR AND CRESCENT
- 0x5B = ☯ U+262F YIN YANG
- 0x5C =  U+1F549 OM SYMBOL
- 0x5D = ☸ U+2638 WHEEL OF DHARMA
- 0x5E = ♈ U+2648 ARIES
- 0x5F = ♉ U+2649 TAURUS
- 0x60 = ♊ U+264A GEMINI
- 0x61 = ♋ U+264B CANCER
- 0x62 = ♌ U+264C LEO
- 0x63 = ♍ U+264D VIRGO
- 0x64 = ♎ U+264E LIBRA
- 0x65 = ♏ U+264F SCORPIUS
- 0x66 = ♐ U+2650 SAGITTARIUS
- 0x67 = ♑ U+2651 CAPRICORN
- 0x68 = ♒ U+2652 AQUARIUS
- 0x69 = ♓ U+2653 PISCES
- 0x6A =  U+1F670 SCRIPT LIGATURE ET ORNAMENT
- 0x6B =  U+1F675 SWASH AMPERSAND ORNAMENT
- 0x6C = ⚫ U+26AB MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE
- 0x6D =  U+1F53E LOWER RIGHT SHADOWED WHITE CIRCLE
- 0x6E = ◼ U+25FC BLACK MEDIUM SQUARE
- 0x6F =  U+1F78F MEDIUM WHITE SQUARE
- 0x70 =  U+1F790 BOLD WHITE SQUARE
- 0x71 = ❑ U+2751 LOWER RIGHT SHADOWED WHITE SQUARE
- 0x72 = ❒ U+2752 UPPER RIGHT SHADOWED WHITE SQUARE
- 0x73 =  U+1F79F BLACK MEDIUM SMALL LOZENGE
- 0x74 = ⧫ U+29EB BLACK LOZENGE
- 0x75 = ◆ U+25C6 BLACK DIAMOND
- 0x76 = ❖ U+2756 BLACK DIAMOND MINUS WHITE X
- 0x77 =  U+1F799 BLACK MEDIUM SMALL DIAMOND
- 0x78 = ⌧ U+2327 X IN A RECTANGLE BOX
- 0x79 = ⮹ U+2BB9 UP ARROWHEAD IN A RECTANGLE BOX
- 0x7A = ⌘ U+2318 PLACE OF INTEREST SIGN
- 0x7B =  U+1F3F5 ROSETTE
- 0x7C =  U+1F3F6 BLACK ROSETTE
- 0x7D =  U+1F676 SANS-SERIF HEAVY DOUBLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
- 0x7E =  U+1F677 SANS-SERIF HEAVY DOUBLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
- 0x7F = ▯ U+25AF WHITE VERTICAL RECTANGLE
- 0x80 =  U+1F10B DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT ZERO
- 0x81 = ➀ U+2780 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT ONE
- 0x82 = ➁ U+2781 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT TWO
- 0x83 = ➂ U+2782 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT THREE
- 0x84 = ➃ U+2783 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT FOUR
- 0x85 = ➄ U+2784 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT FIVE
- 0x86 = ➅ U+2785 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT SIX
- 0x87 = ➆ U+2786 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT SEVEN
- 0x88 = ➇ U+2787 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT EIGHT
- 0x89 = ➈ U+2788 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT NINE
- 0x8A = ➉ U+2789 DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF NUMBER TEN
- 0x8B =  U+1F10C DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT ZERO
- 0x8C = ➊ U+278A DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT ONE
- 0x8D = ➋ U+278B DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT TWO
- 0x8E = ➌ U+278C DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT THREE
- 0x8F = ➍ U+278D DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT FOUR
- 0x90 = ➎ U+278E DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT FIVE
- 0x91 = ➏ U+278F DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT SIX
- 0x92 = ➐ U+2790 DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT SEVEN
- 0x93 = ➑ U+2791 DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT EIGHT
- 0x94 = ➒ U+2792 DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT NINE
- 0x95 = ➓ U+2793 DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF NUMBER TEN
- 0x96 =  U+1F662 NORTH EAST POINTING BUD
- 0x97 =  U+1F660 NORTH WEST POINTING BUD
- 0x98 =  U+1F661 SOUTH WEST POINTING BUD
- 0x99 =  U+1F663 SOUTH EAST POINTING BUD
- 0x9A =  U+1F65E HEAVY NORTH EAST POINTING VINE LEAF
- 0x9B =  U+1F65C HEAVY NORTH WEST POINTING VINE LEAF
- 0x9C =  U+1F65D HEAVY SOUTH WEST POINTING VINE LEAF
- 0x9D =  U+1F65F HEAVY SOUTH EAST POINTING VINE LEAF
- 0x9E = ∙ U+2219 BULLET OPERATOR
- 0x9F = • U+2022 BULLET
- 0xA0 = ⬝ U+2B1D BLACK VERY SMALL SQUARE
- 0xA1 = ⭘ U+2B58 HEAVY CIRCLE
- 0xA2 =  U+1F786 BOLD WHITE CIRCLE
- 0xA3 =  U+1F788 VERY HEAVY WHITE CIRCLE
- 0xA4 =  U+1F78A WHITE CIRCLE CONTAINING BLACK SMALL CIRCLE
- 0xA5 =  U+1F78B ROUND TARGET
- 0xA6 =  U+1F53F UPPER RIGHT SHADOWED WHITE CIRCLE
- 0xA7 = ▪ U+25AA BLACK SMALL SQUARE
- 0xA8 =  U+1F78E LIGHT WHITE SQUARE
- 0xA9 =  U+1F7C1 MEDIUM THREE POINTED BLACK STAR
- 0xAA =  U+1F7C5 MEDIUM FOUR POINTED BLACK STAR
- 0xAB = ★ U+2605 BLACK STAR
- 0xAC =  U+1F7CB MEDIUM SIX POINTED BLACK STAR
- 0xAD =  U+1F7CF HEAVY EIGHT POINTED BLACK STAR
- 0xAE =  U+1F7D3 HEAVY TWELVE POINTED BLACK STAR
- 0xAF =  U+1F7D1 HEAVY EIGHT POINTED PINWHEEL STAR
- 0xB0 = ⯐ U+2BD0 SQUARE POSITION INDICATOR
- 0xB1 = ⌖ U+2316 POSITION INDICATOR
- 0xB2 = ⯎ U+2BCE WHITE FOUR POINTED CUSP
- 0xB3 = ⯏ U+2BCF ROTATED WHITE FOUR POINTED CUSP
- 0xB4 = ⯑ U+2BD1 UNCERTAINTY SIGN
- 0xB5 = ✪ U+272A CIRCLED WHITE STAR
- 0xB6 = ✰ U+2730 SHADOWED WHITE STAR
- 0xB7 =  U+1F550 CLOCK FACE ONE OCLOCK
- 0xB8 =  U+1F551 CLOCK FACE TWO OCLOCK
- 0xB9 =  U+1F552 CLOCK FACE THREE OCLOCK
- 0xBA =  U+1F553 CLOCK FACE FOUR OCLOCK
- 0xBB =  U+1F554 CLOCK FACE FIVE OCLOCK
- 0xBC =  U+1F555 CLOCK FACE SIX OCLOCK
- 0xBD =  U+1F556 CLOCK FACE SEVEN OCLOCK
- 0xBE =  U+1F557 CLOCK FACE EIGHT OCLOCK
- 0xBF =  U+1F558 CLOCK FACE NINE OCLOCK
- 0xC0 =  U+1F559 CLOCK FACE TEN OCLOCK
- 0xC1 =  U+1F55A CLOCK FACE ELEVEN OCLOCK
- 0xC2 =  U+1F55B CLOCK FACE TWELVE OCLOCK
- 0xC3 = ⮰ U+2BB0 RIBBON ARROW DOWN LEFT
- 0xC4 = ⮱ U+2BB1 RIBBON ARROW DOWN RIGHT
- 0xC5 = ⮲ U+2BB2 RIBBON ARROW UP LEFT
- 0xC6 = ⮳ U+2BB3 RIBBON ARROW UP RIGHT
- 0xC7 = ⮴ U+2BB4 RIBBON ARROW LEFT UP
- 0xC8 = ⮵ U+2BB5 RIBBON ARROW RIGHT UP
- 0xC9 = ⮶ U+2BB6 RIBBON ARROW LEFT DOWN
- 0xCA = ⮷ U+2BB7 RIBBON ARROW RIGHT DOWN
- 0xCB =  U+1F66A SOLID QUILT SQUARE ORNAMENT
- 0xCC =  U+1F66B SOLID QUILT SQUARE ORNAMENT IN BLACK SQUARE
- 0xCD =  U+1F655 TURNED SOUTH WEST POINTING LEAF
- 0xCE =  U+1F654 TURNED NORTH WEST POINTING LEAF
- 0xCF =  U+1F657 TURNED SOUTH EAST POINTING LEAF
- 0xD0 =  U+1F656 TURNED NORTH EAST POINTING LEAF
- 0xD1 =  U+1F650 NORTH WEST POINTING LEAF
- 0xD2 =  U+1F651 SOUTH WEST POINTING LEAF
- 0xD3 =  U+1F652 NORTH EAST POINTING LEAF
- 0xD4 =  U+1F653 SOUTH EAST POINTING LEAF
- 0xD5 = ⌫ U+232B ERASE TO THE LEFT
- 0xD6 = ⌦ U+2326 ERASE TO THE RIGHT
- 0xD7 = ⮘ U+2B98 THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED LEFTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD
- 0xD8 = ⮚ U+2B9A THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD
- 0xD9 = ⮙ U+2B99 THREE-D RIGHT-LIGHTED UPWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD
- 0xDA = ⮛ U+2B9B THREE-D LEFT-LIGHTED DOWNWARDS EQUILATERAL ARROWHEAD
- 0xDB = ⮈ U+2B88 LEFTWARDS BLACK CIRCLED WHITE ARROW
- 0xDC = ⮊ U+2B8A RIGHTWARDS BLACK CIRCLED WHITE ARROW
- 0xDD = ⮉ U+2B89 UPWARDS BLACK CIRCLED WHITE ARROW
- 0xDE = ⮋ U+2B8B DOWNWARDS BLACK CIRCLED WHITE ARROW
- 0xDF =  U+1F868 WIDE-HEADED LEFTWARDS BARB ARROW
- 0xE0 =  U+1F86A WIDE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS BARB ARROW
- 0xE1 =  U+1F869 WIDE-HEADED UPWARDS BARB ARROW
- 0xE2 =  U+1F86B WIDE-HEADED DOWNWARDS BARB ARROW
- 0xE3 =  U+1F86C WIDE-HEADED NORTH WEST BARB ARROW
- 0xE4 =  U+1F86D WIDE-HEADED NORTH EAST BARB ARROW
- 0xE5 =  U+1F86F WIDE-HEADED SOUTH WEST BARB ARROW
- 0xE6 =  U+1F86E WIDE-HEADED SOUTH EAST BARB ARROW
- 0xE7 =  U+1F878 WIDE-HEADED LEFTWARDS HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xE8 =  U+1F87A WIDE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xE9 =  U+1F879 WIDE-HEADED UPWARDS HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xEA =  U+1F87B WIDE-HEADED DOWNWARDS HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xEB =  U+1F87C WIDE-HEADED NORTH WEST HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xEC =  U+1F87D WIDE-HEADED NORTH EAST HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xED =  U+1F87F WIDE-HEADED SOUTH WEST HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xEE =  U+1F87E WIDE-HEADED SOUTH EAST HEAVY BARB ARROW
- 0xEF = ⇦ U+21E6 LEFTWARDS WHITE ARROW
- 0xF0 = ⇨ U+21E8 RIGHTWARDS WHITE ARROW
- 0xF1 = ⇧ U+21E7 UPWARDS WHITE ARROW
- 0xF2 = ⇩ U+21E9 DOWNWARDS WHITE ARROW
- 0xF3 = ⬄ U+2B04 LEFT RIGHT WHITE ARROW
- 0xF4 = ⇳ U+21F3 UP DOWN WHITE ARROW
- 0xF5 = ⬁ U+2B01 NORTH WEST WHITE ARROW
- 0xF6 = ⬀ U+2B00 NORTH EAST WHITE ARROW
- 0xF7 = ⬃ U+2B03 SOUTH WEST WHITE ARROW
- 0xF8 = ⬂ U+2B02 SOUTH EAST WHITE ARROW
- 0xF9 =  U+1F8AC WHITE ARROW SHAFT WIDTH ONE
- 0xFA =  U+1F8AD WHITE ARROW SHAFT WIDTH TWO THIRDS
- 0xFB =  U+1F5F6 BALLOT BOLD SCRIPT X
- 0xFC = ✓ U+2713 CHECK MARK
- 0xFD =  U+1F5F7 BALLOT BOX WITH BOLD SCRIPT X
- 0xFE =  U+1F5F9 BALLOT BOX WITH BOLD CHECK
- 0xFF = ⊞ U+229E SQUARED PLUS

The last one is supposed to be the Windows logo, which is not included in Unicode for trademark reasons.  If anybody can find a better approximation, please let me know.

### Webdings

- 0x21 =  U+1F577 SPIDER
- 0x22 =  U+1F578 SPIDER WEB
- 0x23 =  U+1F572 NO PIRACY
- 0x24 =  U+1F576 DARK SUNGLASSES
- 0x25 =  U+1F3C6 TROPHY
- 0x26 =  U+1F396 MILITARY MEDAL
- 0x27 =  U+1F587 LINKED PAPERCLIPS
- 0x28 =  U+1F5E8 LEFT SPEECH BUBBLE
- 0x29 =  U+1F5E9 RIGHT SPEECH BUBBLE
- 0x2A =  U+1F5F0 MOOD BUBBLE
- 0x2B =  U+1F5F1 LIGHTNING MOOD BUBBLE
- 0x2C =  U+1F336 HOT PEPPER
- 0x2D =  U+1F397 REMINDER RIBBON
- 0x2E =  U+1F67E CHECKER BOARD
- 0x2F =  U+1F67C VERY HEAVY SOLIDUS
- 0x30 =  U+1F5D5 MINIMIZE
- 0x31 =  U+1F5D6 MAXIMIZE
- 0x32 =  U+1F5D7 OVERLAP
- 0x33 = ⏴ U+23F4 BLACK MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE
- 0x34 = ⏵ U+23F5 BLACK MEDIUM RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE
- 0x35 = ⏶ U+23F6 BLACK MEDIUM UP-POINTING TRIANGLE
- 0x36 = ⏷ U+23F7 BLACK MEDIUM DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE
- 0x37 = ⏪ U+23EA BLACK LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE
- 0x38 = ⏩ U+23E9 BLACK RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE
- 0x39 = ⏮ U+23EE BLACK LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE WITH VERTICAL BAR
- 0x3A = ⏭ U+23ED BLACK RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE WITH VERTICAL BAR
- 0x3B = ⏸ U+23F8 DOUBLE VERTICAL BAR
- 0x3C = ⏹ U+23F9 BLACK SQUARE FOR STOP
- 0x3D = ⏺ U+23FA BLACK CIRCLE FOR RECORD
- 0x3E =  U+1F5DA INCREASE FONT SIZE SYMBOL
- 0x3F =  U+1F5F3 BALLOT BOX WITH BALLOT
- 0x40 =  U+1F6E0 HAMMER AND WRENCH
- 0x41 =  U+1F3D7 BUILDING CONSTRUCTION
- 0x42 =  U+1F3D8 HOUSE BUILDINGS
- 0x43 =  U+1F3D9 CITYSCAPE
- 0x44 =  U+1F3DA DERELICT HOUSE BUILDING
- 0x45 =  U+1F3DC DESERT
- 0x46 =  U+1F3ED FACTORY
- 0x47 =  U+1F3DB CLASSICAL BUILDING
- 0x48 =  U+1F3E0 HOUSE BUILDING
- 0x49 =  U+1F3D6 BEACH WITH UMBRELLA
- 0x4A =  U+1F3DD DESERT ISLAND
- 0x4B =  U+1F6E3 MOTORWAY
- 0x4C =  U+1F50D LEFT-POINTING MAGNIFYING GLASS
- 0x4D =  U+1F3D4 SNOW CAPPED MOUNTAIN
- 0x4E =  U+1F441 EYE
- 0x4F =  U+1F442 EAR
- 0x50 =  U+1F3DE NATIONAL PARK
- 0x51 =  U+1F3D5 CAMPING
- 0x52 =  U+1F6E4 RAILWAY TRACK
- 0x53 =  U+1F3DF STADIUM
- 0x54 =  U+1F6F3 PASSENGER SHIP
- 0x55 =  U+1F56C BULLHORN WITH SOUND WAVES
- 0x56 =  U+1F56B BULLHORN
- 0x57 =  U+1F568 RIGHT SPEAKER
- 0x58 =  U+1F508 SPEAKER
- 0x59 =  U+1F394 HEART WITH TIP ON THE LEFT
- 0x5A =  U+1F395 BOUQUET OF FLOWERS
- 0x5B =  U+1F5EC LEFT THOUGHT BUBBLE
- 0x5C =  U+1F67D VERY HEAVY REVERSE SOLIDUS
- 0x5D =  U+1F5ED RIGHT THOUGHT BUBBLE
- 0x5E =  U+1F5EA TWO SPEECH BUBBLES
- 0x5F =  U+1F5EB THREE SPEECH BUBBLES
- 0x60 = ⮔ U+2B94 FOUR CORNER ARROWS CIRCLING ANTICLOCKWISE
- 0x61 = ✔ U+2714 HEAVY CHECK MARK
- 0x62 =  U+1F6B2 BICYCLE
- 0x63 = ⬜ U+2B1C WHITE LARGE SQUARE
- 0x64 =  U+1F6E1 SHIELD
- 0x65 =  U+1F381 WRAPPED PRESENT
- 0x66 =  U+1F6F1 ONCOMING FIRE ENGINE
- 0x67 = ⬛ U+2B1B BLACK LARGE SQUARE
- 0x68 =  U+1F691 AMBULANCE
- 0x69 =  U+1F6C8 CIRCLED INFORMATION SOURCE
- 0x6A =  U+1F6E9 SMALL AIRPLANE
- 0x6B =  U+1F6F0 SATELLITE
- 0x6C =  U+1F7C8 REVERSE LIGHT FOUR POINTED PINWHEEL STAR
- 0x6D =  U+1F574 MAN IN BUSINESS SUIT LEVITATING
- 0x6E = ⬤ U+2B24 BLACK LARGE CIRCLE
- 0x6F =  U+1F6E5 MOTOR BOAT
- 0x70 =  U+1F694 ONCOMING POLICE CAR
- 0x71 =  U+1F5D8 CLOCKWISE RIGHT AND LEFT SEMICIRCLE ARROWS
- 0x72 =  U+1F5D9 CANCELLATION X
- 0x73 = ❓ U+2753 BLACK QUESTION MARK ORNAMENT
- 0x74 =  U+1F6F2 DIESEL LOCOMOTIVE
- 0x75 =  U+1F687 METRO
- 0x76 =  U+1F68D ONCOMING BUS
- 0x77 =  U+1F6A9 TRIANGULAR FLAG ON POST
- 0x78 = ⦸ U+29B8 CIRCLED REVERSE SOLIDUS
- 0x79 = ⊖ U+2296 CIRCLED MINUS
- 0x7A =  U+1F6AD NO SMOKING SYMBOL
- 0x7B =  U+1F5EE LEFT ANGER BUBBLE
- 0x7C = ⏐ U+23D0 VERTICAL LINE EXTENSION
- 0x7D =  U+1F5EF RIGHT ANGER BUBBLE
- 0x7E =  U+1F5F2 LIGHTNING MOOD
- 0x7F = ▯ U+25AF WHITE VERTICAL RECTANGLE
- 0x80 =  U+1F6B9 MENS SYMBOL
- 0x81 =  U+1F6BA WOMENS SYMBOL
- 0x82 =  U+1F6C9 BOYS SYMBOL
- 0x83 =  U+1F6CA GIRLS SYMBOL
- 0x84 =  U+1F6BC BABY SYMBOL
- 0x85 =  U+1F47D EXTRATERRESTRIAL ALIEN
- 0x86 =  U+1F3CB WEIGHT LIFTER
- 0x87 = ⛷ U+26F7 SKIER
- 0x88 =  U+1F3C2 SNOWBOARDER
- 0x89 =  U+1F3CC GOLFER
- 0x8A =  U+1F3CA SWIMMER
- 0x8B =  U+1F3C4 SURFER
- 0x8C =  U+1F3CD RACING MOTORCYCLE
- 0x8D =  U+1F3CE RACING CAR
- 0x8E =  U+1F698 ONCOMING AUTOMOBILE
- 0x8F =  U+1F4C8 CHART WITH UPWARDS TREND
- 0x90 =  U+1F6E2 OIL DRUM
- 0x91 =  U+1F4B0 MONEY BAG
- 0x92 =  U+1F3F7 LABEL
- 0x93 =  U+1F4B3 CREDIT CARD
- 0x94 =  U+1F46A FAMILY
- 0x95 =  U+1F5E1 DAGGER KNIFE
- 0x96 =  U+1F5E2 LIPS
- 0x97 =  U+1F5E3 SPEAKING HEAD IN SILHOUETTE
- 0x98 = ✯ U+272F PINWHEEL STAR
- 0x99 =  U+1F584 ENVELOPE WITH LIGHTNING
- 0x9A =  U+1F585 FLYING ENVELOPE
- 0x9B =  U+1F583 STAMPED ENVELOPE
- 0x9C =  U+1F586 PEN OVER STAMPED ENVELOPE
- 0x9D =  U+1F5B9 DOCUMENT WITH TEXT
- 0x9E =  U+1F5BA DOCUMENT WITH TEXT AND PICTURE
- 0x9F =  U+1F5BB DOCUMENT WITH PICTURE
- 0xA0 =  U+1F575 SLEUTH OR SPY
- 0xA1 =  U+1F570 MANTELPIECE CLOCK
- 0xA2 =  U+1F5BD FRAME WITH TILES
- 0xA3 =  U+1F5BE FRAME WITH AN X
- 0xA4 =  U+1F4CB CLIPBOARD
- 0xA5 =  U+1F5D2 SPIRAL NOTE PAD
- 0xA6 =  U+1F5D3 SPIRAL CALENDAR PAD
- 0xA7 =  U+1F56E BOOK
- 0xA8 =  U+1F4DA BOOKS
- 0xA9 =  U+1F5DE ROLLED-UP NEWSPAPER
- 0xAA =  U+1F5DF PAGE WITH CIRCLED TEXT
- 0xAB =  U+1F5C3 CARD FILE BOX
- 0xAC =  U+1F4C7 CARD INDEX
- 0xAD =  U+1F5BC FRAME WITH PICTURE
- 0xAE =  U+1F3AD PERFORMING ARTS
- 0xAF =  U+1F39C BEAMED ASCENDING MUSICAL NOTES
- 0xB0 =  U+1F398 MUSICAL KEYBOARD WITH JACKS
- 0xB1 =  U+1F399 STUDIO MICROPHONE
- 0xB2 =  U+1F3A7 HEADPHONE
- 0xB3 =  U+1F4BF OPTICAL DISC
- 0xB4 =  U+1F39E FILM FRAMES
- 0xB5 =  U+1F4F7 CAMERA
- 0xB6 =  U+1F39F ADMISSION TICKETS
- 0xB7 =  U+1F3AC CLAPPER BOARD
- 0xB8 =  U+1F4FD FILM PROJECTOR
- 0xB9 =  U+1F4F9 VIDEO CAMERA
- 0xBA =  U+1F4FE PORTABLE STEREO
- 0xBB =  U+1F4FB RADIO
- 0xBC =  U+1F39A LEVEL SLIDER
- 0xBD =  U+1F39B CONTROL KNOBS
- 0xBE =  U+1F4FA TELEVISION
- 0xBF =  U+1F4BB PERSONAL COMPUTER
- 0xC0 =  U+1F5A5 DESKTOP COMPUTER
- 0xC1 =  U+1F5A6 KEYBOARD AND MOUSE
- 0xC2 =  U+1F5A7 THREE NETWORKED COMPUTERS
- 0xC3 =  U+1F579 JOYSTICK
- 0xC4 =  U+1F3AE VIDEO GAME
- 0xC5 =  U+1F57B LEFT HAND TELEPHONE RECEIVER
- 0xC6 =  U+1F57C TELEPHONE RECEIVER WITH PAGE
- 0xC7 =  U+1F4DF PAGER
- 0xC8 =  U+1F581 CLAMSHELL MOBILE PHONE
- 0xC9 =  U+1F580 TELEPHONE ON TOP OF MODEM
- 0xCA =  U+1F5A8 PRINTER
- 0xCB =  U+1F5A9 POCKET CALCULATOR
- 0xCC =  U+1F5BF BLACK FOLDER
- 0xCD =  U+1F5AA BLACK HARD SHELL FLOPPY DISK
- 0xCE =  U+1F5DC COMPRESSION
- 0xCF =  U+1F512 LOCK
- 0xD0 =  U+1F513 OPEN LOCK
- 0xD1 =  U+1F5DD OLD KEY
- 0xD2 =  U+1F4E5 INBOX TRAY
- 0xD3 =  U+1F4E4 OUTBOX TRAY
- 0xD4 =  U+1F573 HOLE
- 0xD5 =  U+1F323 WHITE SUN
- 0xD6 =  U+1F324 WHITE SUN WITH SMALL CLOUD
- 0xD7 =  U+1F325 WHITE SUN BEHIND CLOUD
- 0xD8 =  U+1F326 WHITE SUN BEHIND CLOUD WITH RAIN
- 0xD9 = ☁ U+2601 CLOUD
- 0xDA =  U+1F328 CLOUD WITH SNOW
- 0xDB =  U+1F327 CLOUD WITH RAIN
- 0xDC =  U+1F329 CLOUD WITH LIGHTNING
- 0xDD =  U+1F32A CLOUD WITH TORNADO
- 0xDE =  U+1F32C WIND BLOWING FACE
- 0xDF =  U+1F32B FOG
- 0xE0 =  U+1F31C LAST QUARTER MOON WITH FACE
- 0xE1 =  U+1F321 THERMOMETER
- 0xE2 =  U+1F6CB COUCH AND LAMP
- 0xE3 =  U+1F6CF BED
- 0xE4 =  U+1F37D FORK AND KNIFE WITH PLATE
- 0xE5 =  U+1F378 COCKTAIL GLASS
- 0xE6 =  U+1F6CE BELLHOP BELL
- 0xE7 =  U+1F6CD SHOPPING BAGS
- 0xE8 = Ⓟ U+24C5 CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
- 0xE9 = ♿ U+267F WHEELCHAIR SYMBOL
- 0xEA =  U+1F6C6 TRIANGLE WITH ROUNDED CORNERS
- 0xEB =  U+1F588 BLACK PUSHPIN
- 0xEC =  U+1F393 GRADUATION CAP
- 0xED =  U+1F5E4 THREE RAYS ABOVE
- 0xEE =  U+1F5E5 THREE RAYS BELOW
- 0xEF =  U+1F5E6 THREE RAYS LEFT
- 0xF0 =  U+1F5E7 THREE RAYS RIGHT
- 0xF1 =  U+1F6EA NORTHEAST-POINTING AIRPLANE
- 0xF2 =  U+1F43F CHIPMUNK
- 0xF3 =  U+1F426 BIRD
- 0xF4 =  U+1F41F FISH
- 0xF5 =  U+1F415 DOG
- 0xF6 =  U+1F408 CAT
- 0xF7 =  U+1F66C LEFTWARDS ROCKET
- 0xF8 =  U+1F66E RIGHTWARDS ROCKET
- 0xF9 =  U+1F66D UPWARDS ROCKET
- 0xFA =  U+1F66F DOWNWARDS ROCKET
- 0xFB =  U+1F5FA WORLD MAP
- 0xFC =  U+1F30D EARTH GLOBE EUROPE-AFRICA
- 0xFD =  U+1F30F EARTH GLOBE ASIA-AUSTRALIA
- 0xFE =  U+1F30E EARTH GLOBE AMERICAS
- 0xFF =  U+1F54A DOVE OF PEACE

### Symbol

- 0x21 = ! U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK
- 0x22 = ∀ U+2200 FOR ALL
- 0x23 = # U+0023 NUMBER SIGN
- 0x24 = ∃ U+2203 THERE EXISTS
- 0x25 = % U+0025 PERCENT SIGN
- 0x26 = & U+0026 AMPERSAND
- 0x27 = ∋ U+220B CONTAINS AS MEMBER
- 0x28 = ( U+0028 LEFT PARENTHESIS
- 0x29 = ) U+0029 RIGHT PARENTHESIS
- 0x2A = ∗ U+2217 ASTERISK OPERATOR
- 0x2B = + U+002B PLUS SIGN
- 0x2C = , U+002C COMMA
- 0x2D = − U+2212 MINUS SIGN
- 0x2E = . U+002E FULL STOP
- 0x2F = / U+002F SOLIDUS
- 0x30 = 0 U+0030 DIGIT ZERO
- 0x31 = 1 U+0031 DIGIT ONE
- 0x32 = 2 U+0032 DIGIT TWO
- 0x33 = 3 U+0033 DIGIT THREE
- 0x34 = 4 U+0034 DIGIT FOUR
- 0x35 = 5 U+0035 DIGIT FIVE
- 0x36 = 6 U+0036 DIGIT SIX
- 0x37 = 7 U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN
- 0x38 = 8 U+0038 DIGIT EIGHT
- 0x39 = 9 U+0039 DIGIT NINE
- 0x3A = : U+003A COLON
- 0x3B = ; U+003B SEMICOLON
- 0x3C = < U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN
- 0x3D = = U+003D EQUALS SIGN
- 0x3E = > U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN
- 0x3F = ? U+003F QUESTION MARK
- 0x40 = ≅ U+2245 APPROXIMATELY EQUAL TO
- 0x41 = Α U+0391 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA
- 0x42 = Β U+0392 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER BETA
- 0x43 = Χ U+03A7 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER CHI
- 0x44 = Δ U+0394 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA
- 0x45 = Ε U+0395 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER EPSILON
- 0x46 = Φ U+03A6 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PHI
- 0x47 = Γ U+0393 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER GAMMA
- 0x48 = Η U+0397 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA
- 0x49 = Ι U+0399 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER IOTA
- 0x4A = ϑ U+03D1 GREEK THETA SYMBOL
- 0x4B = Κ U+039A GREEK CAPITAL LETTER KAPPA
- 0x4C = Λ U+039B GREEK CAPITAL LETTER LAMBDA
- 0x4D = Μ U+039C GREEK CAPITAL LETTER MU
- 0x4E = Ν U+039D GREEK CAPITAL LETTER NU
- 0x4F = Ο U+039F GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMICRON
- 0x50 = Π U+03A0 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PI
- 0x51 = Θ U+0398 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER THETA
- 0x52 = Ρ U+03A1 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER RHO
- 0x53 = Σ U+03A3 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA
- 0x54 = Τ U+03A4 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER TAU
- 0x55 = Υ U+03A5 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER UPSILON
- 0x56 = ς U+03C2 GREEK SMALL LETTER FINAL SIGMA
- 0x57 = Ω U+03A9 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA
- 0x58 = Ξ U+039E GREEK CAPITAL LETTER XI
- 0x59 = Ψ U+03A8 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PSI
- 0x5A = Ζ U+0396 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ZETA
- 0x5B = [ U+005B LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
- 0x5C = ∴ U+2234 THEREFORE
- 0x5D = ] U+005D RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
- 0x5E = ⊥ U+22A5 UP TACK
- 0x5F = _ U+005F LOW LINE
- 0x60 = ‾ U+203E OVERLINE
- 0x61 = α U+03B1 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
- 0x62 = β U+03B2 GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA
- 0x63 = χ U+03C7 GREEK SMALL LETTER CHI
- 0x64 = δ U+03B4 GREEK SMALL LETTER DELTA
- 0x65 = ε U+03B5 GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON
- 0x66 = φ U+03C6 GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI
- 0x67 = γ U+03B3 GREEK SMALL LETTER GAMMA
- 0x68 = η U+03B7 GREEK SMALL LETTER ETA
- 0x69 = ι U+03B9 GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA
- 0x6A = ϕ U+03D5 GREEK PHI SYMBOL
- 0x6B = κ U+03BA GREEK SMALL LETTER KAPPA
- 0x6C = λ U+03BB GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA
- 0x6D = μ U+03BC GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
- 0x6E = ν U+03BD GREEK SMALL LETTER NU
- 0x6F = ο U+03BF GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON
- 0x70 = π U+03C0 GREEK SMALL LETTER PI
- 0x71 = θ U+03B8 GREEK SMALL LETTER THETA
- 0x72 = ρ U+03C1 GREEK SMALL LETTER RHO
- 0x73 = σ U+03C3 GREEK SMALL LETTER SIGMA
- 0x74 = τ U+03C4 GREEK SMALL LETTER TAU
- 0x75 = υ U+03C5 GREEK SMALL LETTER UPSILON
- 0x76 = ϖ U+03D6 GREEK PI SYMBOL
- 0x77 = ω U+03C9 GREEK SMALL LETTER OMEGA
- 0x78 = ξ U+03BE GREEK SMALL LETTER XI
- 0x79 = ψ U+03C8 GREEK SMALL LETTER PSI
- 0x7A = ζ U+03B6 GREEK SMALL LETTER ZETA
- 0x7B = { U+007B LEFT CURLY BRACKET
- 0x7C = | U+007C VERTICAL LINE
- 0x7D = } U+007D RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
- 0x7E = ∼ U+223C TILDE OPERATOR
- (0xA0 = € U+20AC EURO SIGN) — not in all versions of the font
- 0xA1 = ϒ U+03D2 GREEK UPSILON WITH HOOK SYMBOL
- 0xA2 = ′ U+2032 PRIME
- 0xA3 = ≤ U+2264 LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO
- 0xA4 = ⁄ U+2044 FRACTION SLASH
- 0xA5 = ∞ U+221E INFINITY
- 0xA6 = ƒ U+0192 LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK
- 0xA7 = ♣ U+2663 BLACK CLUB SUIT
- 0xA8 = ♦ U+2666 BLACK DIAMOND SUIT
- 0xA9 = ♥ U+2665 BLACK HEART SUIT
- 0xAA = ♠ U+2660 BLACK SPADE SUIT
- 0xAB = ↔ U+2194 LEFT RIGHT ARROW
- 0xAC = ← U+2190 LEFTWARDS ARROW
- 0xAD = ↑ U+2191 UPWARDS ARROW
- 0xAE = → U+2192 RIGHTWARDS ARROW
- 0xAF = ↓ U+2193 DOWNWARDS ARROW
- 0xB0 = ° U+00B0 DEGREE SIGN
- 0xB1 = ± U+00B1 PLUS-MINUS SIGN
- 0xB2 = ″ U+2033 DOUBLE PRIME
- 0xB3 = ≥ U+2265 GREATER-THAN OR EQUAL TO
- 0xB4 = × U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN
- 0xB5 = ∝ U+221D PROPORTIONAL TO
- 0xB6 = ∂ U+2202 PARTIAL DIFFERENTIAL
- 0xB7 = • U+2022 BULLET
- 0xB8 = ÷ U+00F7 DIVISION SIGN
- 0xB9 = ≠ U+2260 NOT EQUAL TO
- 0xBA = ≡ U+2261 IDENTICAL TO
- 0xBB = ≈ U+2248 ALMOST EQUAL TO
- 0xBC = … U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
- 0xBD = ⏐ U+23D0 VERTICAL LINE EXTENSION
- 0xBE = ⎯ U+23AF HORIZONTAL LINE EXTENSION
- 0xBF = ↵ U+21B5 DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS
- 0xC0 = ℵ U+2135 ALEF SYMBOL
- 0xC1 = ℑ U+2111 BLACK-LETTER CAPITAL I
- 0xC2 = ℜ U+211C BLACK-LETTER CAPITAL R
- 0xC3 = ℘ U+2118 SCRIPT CAPITAL P
- 0xC4 = ⊗ U+2297 CIRCLED TIMES
- 0xC5 = ⊕ U+2295 CIRCLED PLUS
- 0xC6 = ∅ U+2205 EMPTY SET
- 0xC7 = ∩ U+2229 INTERSECTION
- 0xC8 = ∪ U+222A UNION
- 0xC9 = ⊃ U+2283 SUPERSET OF
- 0xCA = ⊇ U+2287 SUPERSET OF OR EQUAL TO
- 0xCB = ⊄ U+2284 NOT A SUBSET OF
- 0xCC = ⊂ U+2282 SUBSET OF
- 0xCD = ⊆ U+2286 SUBSET OF OR EQUAL TO
- 0xCE = ∈ U+2208 ELEMENT OF
- 0xCF = ∉ U+2209 NOT AN ELEMENT OF
- 0xD0 = ∠ U+2220 ANGLE
- 0xD1 = ∇ U+2207 NABLA
- 0xD2 = ® U+00AE REGISTERED SIGN
- 0xD3 = © U+00A9 COPYRIGHT SIGN
- 0xD4 = ™ U+2122 TRADE MARK SIGN
- 0xD5 = ∏ U+220F N-ARY PRODUCT
- 0xD6 = √ U+221A SQUARE ROOT
- 0xD7 = ⋅ U+22C5 DOT OPERATOR
- 0xD8 = ¬ U+00AC NOT SIGN
- 0xD9 = ∧ U+2227 LOGICAL AND
- 0xDA = ∨ U+2228 LOGICAL OR
- 0xDB = ⇔ U+21D4 LEFT RIGHT DOUBLE ARROW
- 0xDC = ⇐ U+21D0 LEFTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
- 0xDD = ⇑ U+21D1 UPWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
- 0xDE = ⇒ U+21D2 RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
- 0xDF = ⇓ U+21D3 DOWNWARDS DOUBLE ARROW
- 0xE0 = ◊ U+25CA LOZENGE
- 0xE1 = ⟨ U+27E8 MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET
- 0xE2 = ® U+00AE REGISTERED SIGN
- 0xE3 = © U+00A9 COPYRIGHT SIGN
- 0xE4 = ™ U+2122 TRADE MARK SIGN
- 0xE5 = ∑ U+2211 N-ARY SUMMATION
- 0xE6 = ⎛ U+239B LEFT PARENTHESIS UPPER HOOK
- 0xE7 = ⎜ U+239C LEFT PARENTHESIS EXTENSION
- 0xE8 = ⎝ U+239D LEFT PARENTHESIS LOWER HOOK
- 0xE9 = ⎡ U+23A1 LEFT SQUARE BRACKET UPPER CORNER
- 0xEA = ⎢ U+23A2 LEFT SQUARE BRACKET EXTENSION
- 0xEB = ⎣ U+23A3 LEFT SQUARE BRACKET LOWER CORNER
- 0xEC = ⎧ U+23A7 LEFT CURLY BRACKET UPPER HOOK
- 0xED = ⎨ U+23A8 LEFT CURLY BRACKET MIDDLE PIECE
- 0xEE = ⎩ U+23A9 LEFT CURLY BRACKET LOWER HOOK
- 0xEF = ⎪ U+23AA CURLY BRACKET EXTENSION
- 0xF1 = ⟩ U+27E9 MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET
- 0xF2 = ∫ U+222B INTEGRAL
- 0xF3 = ⌠ U+2320 TOP HALF INTEGRAL
- 0xF4 = ⎮ U+23AE INTEGRAL EXTENSION
- 0xF5 = ⌡ U+2321 BOTTOM HALF INTEGRAL
- 0xF6 = ⎞ U+239E RIGHT PARENTHESIS UPPER HOOK
- 0xF7 = ⎟ U+239F RIGHT PARENTHESIS EXTENSION
- 0xF8 = ⎠ U+23A0 RIGHT PARENTHESIS LOWER HOOK
- 0xF9 = ⎤ U+23A4 RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET UPPER CORNER
- 0xFA = ⎥ U+23A5 RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET EXTENSION
- 0xFB = ⎦ U+23A6 RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET LOWER CORNER
- 0xFC = ⎫ U+23AB RIGHT CURLY BRACKET UPPER HOOK
- 0xFD = ⎬ U+23AC RIGHT CURLY BRACKET MIDDLE PIECE
- 0xFE = ⎭ U+23AD RIGHT CURLY BRACKET LOWER HOOK

Note that the digits 0-9 and the punctuation marks `!#%&()+,./:;<=>?[]_{|}` are the same as in ASCII.

The characters `©®™` are encoded twice, with slightly different glyphs: the first set (0xD2-0xD4) uses a serif font for the letters, while the second set (0xE2-0xE4) uses a sans-serif font.  This distinction may or may not be relevant to your font-substitution purposes.

Comment: There are three defects within the `Symbol` table.  One I addressed on [the talk page of the corresponding Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Symbol_(typeface)#%E2%88%8B_symbol).  The other is that for angle brackets you use deprecated codepoints (it was found that they cause problems with the renderers — since they are aliases for CJK symbols).  One should use ⟨ and ⟩ instead.  Third, € appears in position `0xa0`, not `0xf0`

Comment: The “ding” mappings are defined by the document [N4384](https://www.unicode.org/wg2/docs/n4384.pdf).  I found a way to scrape this document into machine-readable tables, and found 3 minor errors in your mappings for `Wingdings`.  They are `U+231B` vs `U+23F3 ⏳ HOURGLASS WITH FLOWING SAND`;   `U+261f` vs `U+1F597  WHITE DOWN POINTING LEFT HAND INDEX` and `U+2B29 BLACK SMALL DIAMOND` vs  `1F799  BLACK MEDIUM SMALL DIAMOND`.

Comment: @IlyaZakharevich: For Symbol, I've corrected the ∋⟨⟩ characters.  On my Windows PC, the "Symbol" font doesn't seem to include € at all, but renders both `\xA0` and `\xF0` as "unknown character" glyphs.  I don't recall where I got `\xF0` from; maybe a Linux system.

Answer (score 2):

Such information is embedded in the .ttf file itself - I'm not sure how to access it in java.

AFAIK java.awt.Font only supports unicode - [Apache PdfBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) *may* have classes/methods for your needs (it has a ttf parser, if I remember)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, giorgiga. The `cmap` table in the ttf format seems to contain the mapping, http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=IWS-Chapter08#ba57949e

Comment: @AdamSchmideg why did you unaccept my answer after 7 years?

Comment: Sorry @giorgiga, It's not about your answer, I found the other, more recent answer more up-to-date and detailed, so I accepted it. It caused your answer to be unaccepted.

Answer (score 1):

`dan04`’s answer is very helpful.  On the other hand, it has defects, and nowadays, the relevant resource are the tables in Wikipedia pages for [Symbol font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdings#Character_set), for [Webdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdings#Character_set) and for [Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings#Character_set) (see also two following tables).  The tables had their defects too — but it is much more productive to fix errors in Wikipedia than on SE!

So: as of yesterday, these had been minor problems on these pages (very similar to those in `dan04`’s answer), but as far as I know, they are all either fixed now, or [mentioned on the Talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Symbol_(typeface)#%E2%88%8B_symbol).  To scrape the source of the tables and get a machine-readable form, one can use

```
perl -wne "print qq(\n) if /chset-left1/; next unless /chset-(ctrl|cell)1\|(?:(?:u=|U\+)(\w+))?/; $p = 5>length($2||0) && q(); print q(0x), $p, $2||q(), q(, )" symb-wiki   >symb-wiki-init
```

on the content of the “Edit” pages (on Unix, convert the `" "`-quotes to `' '` quotes).