# How to use Unicode fonts in java FX?

Tags: javafx, unicode, fonts, combobox

how to use unicode fonts in  java fx combobox? The resaon is font type like windings are not getting displayed on combobox. Can anyone help out on this?

Comment: please, tell more details. Maybe you can use fx-css to set  combobox font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unicode symbols use `"\u+code"` , e.g. `"\u2705"`.

Fonts are specified with `-fx-font-family: Fontname;`
More examples for (external) fonts can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173288/specifying-external-font-in-javafx-css/12173413).

However, according to the [bug tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187460) fonts like wingdings can't be used. But there are some similar symbols in unicode: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346962/mapping-between-wingdings-symbol-characters-and-their-unicode-equivalents)